Dyntopo is sharpening edges
I'm using blender 4.2.0 (Windows), and Dyntopo is showing a very unpleasant behavior.
Whenever I click to sculpt (any brush), dyntopo subdivides the mesh, but it's doing it without considering any type of curvature and just making very ugly sharp edges.
So, the image below is the original mesh (before sculpting):

there are currently no modifiers in the object;
already did the vertice merges;
already did the face orientation check;
shade smooth is on


And this is what happens when I click (just a single click, any brush)


So, is there a way to solve this? Is this a configuration somewhere? Is it a bug? Or is it expected behavior? (I don't see this happening in tutorials)
